# Show loading animation while jquery plugin for rich text editor (TinyMCE) is loading on the PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I want to show loading animation when TinyMCE editor is loading on the page. Following is the PHP and JavaScript code.

```
/* PHP */
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="loading" class="center">
    <img id="loading-image" src="<?php echo base_url('js/images/loading_spinner.gif');?>" alt="Loading..."/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="div_question_add_editor">
    <textarea id="textarea_question_add_editor" name="textarea_question_add_editor">Type Question Here...</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

/* JavaScript */
$( "#textarea_question_add_editor" ).load(function(){
  $( "#loading" ).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the TinyMCE own load function? This is for TinyMCE version 4

```
 tinymce.init({
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('LoadContent', function(e) {
          //Add your hide code here
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The console shows me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: @TejasNavghane Good :)